# Checking for presence of keyword arguments in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function that passes a keyword argument to a function in the following way

```
 (defun hyphenate (string &key upper lower)
  (do ((s (cdr (coerce string 'list)) (cdr s))
       (acc (string (char string 0))))
      ((null s) (cond
                 (lower (string-downcase acc))
                 (t (string-upcase acc))))
     (cond
      ((upper-case-p (car s)) (setf acc (concatenate 'string
                                                     (concatenate 'string acc "-")
                                                     (string (car s)))))
      (t (setf acc (concatenate 'string acc (string (car s)))))))))
```

Basically if the function receives the keyword upper, it will call string-upcase , and if it receives the key lower, it will do a string-downcase.

I just don't know what the appropriate way to test for these arguments is in my function. I don't want to bind them to a value. I just want to call them like this

(hyphenate "jobPostings" :upper)

How do I check for the presence of :upper in the function call? It keeps telling me there is an "unpaired keyword passed to hyphenate"

Comment: Why does this not bind my keyword arguments?!?!

Answer (score 6):

A keyword as an argument and *keyword arguments* are two different things. *keyword arguments* are named arguments. They come as **two items**: a *name* and a *value*.

Like this:

```
CL-USER 1 > (defun hyphenate (string &key upper lower) (list string upper lower))
HYPHENATE
```

You need to give **a name and a value**. Note that the keyword argument which is not passed in has a value of NIL.

```
CL-USER 2 > (hyphenate "foo" :upper t)
("foo" T NIL)
```

Compare that with *optional* arguments:

```
CL-USER 3 > (defun hyphenate (string &optional case) (list string case))
HYPHENATE
```

Now you only need to give the optional argument, which can be the symbol `:upper`.

```
CL-USER 4 > (hyphenate "foo" :upper)
("foo" :UPPER)
```

Or you use a named keyword argument, where you pass in the case symbol:

```
CL-USER 5 > (defun hyphenate (string &key case) (list string case))
HYPHENATE
```

Again, as two items: a name and the value:

```
CL-USER 6 > (hyphenate "foo" :case :upper)
("foo" :UPPER)
```

Some comments about your function:

- if you check a predicate, use IF, not COND
- you are iterating over a string and first converting it to a string. Usually you would iterate over the string using an index.
- you are concatenating single characters to a string over and over in the `DO` loop. That's ugly. if you are already using a list for the input, why not use a list for the output also and convert it back to a string on exit?

If you want to stay with the idea to use lists, you want to map over the list.

```
(defun hyphenate (string  &key (case :upper))
  (map 'string
       (if (eq case :upper) #'char-upcase #'char-downcase)
       (destructuring-bind (start . rest)
           (coerce string 'list)
         (cons start
               (mapcan (lambda (char)
                         (if (upper-case-p char)
                             (list #\- char)
                           (list char)))
                       rest)))))
```

The `MAPCAN` inserts the necessary hyphens. The outer `MAP` converts the case and returns a string.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way keyword arguments work.

Given this:

```
(defun hyphenate (string &key upper lower)
  ...)
```

You'd invoke it like this:

```
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :lower t)
"foo-bar"
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :upper t)
"FOO-BAR"
> (hyphenate "fooBar")
"FOO-BAR"
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :upper t :lower t)
"foo-bar"
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :upper)
ERROR: keyword argument list not of even length
[1]>
```

Basically, keyword arguments are given as an inline [property list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list) after required and optional arguments.

Perhaps what you want is:

```
(defun hyphenate (string &optional (case :lower))
  (assert (member case '(:lower :upper)))
  (let ((lower (eq case :lower)))
    ...))
```

And now you call it like this:

```
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :lower)
"foo-bar"
> (hyphenate "fooBar" :upper)
"FOO-BAR"
> (hyphenate "fooBar")
"foo-bar"
> (hyphenate "fooBar" nil)
ERROR: (assert (member nil '(:lower :upper))) failed
[1]>
```

You may want to reconsider your function to accept `nil` so that no case function is called. But since I don't know how you'll use it, this is a mere suggestion.

However, there are other things you should consider for this function.

For instance, you're converting the origin string into a list. If `hyphenate` is called very often, you'll probably notice a performance hit. It would be better if you'd access the origin string directly.

You could also pre-allocate the new string with `(make-string (+ (length string) num-hyphens))`.

Finally, you could use [`nstring-upcase` and `nstring-downcase`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stg_up.htm), since the generated string is always fresh.

---

PS: In Common Lisp, it's possible to know if an optional or keyword argument was actually provided with an extra variable in the parameter's declaration in the [lambda list](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_da.htm):

```
(defun foo (string &optional (opt (default-opt-expression) opt-supplied-p))
  ...)

(defun bar (string &key (key (default-key-expression) key-supplied-p))
  ...)
```

In these examples, `opt-supplied-p` and `key-supplied-p` are booleans stating if the arguments were supplied.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you wanted something like this, right?

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
(defun hyphenate (string &key (transform-case #'identity))
  (reduce
   #'(lambda (a b)
       (concatenate 'string a (when (> (length a) 0) "-")
                    (funcall transform-case b)))
          (cl-ppcre:split "(?=[A-Z])" string) :initial-value ""))

(hyphenate "fooBarBaz")
"foo-Bar-Baz"

(hyphenate "fooBarBaz" :transform-case #'string-downcase)
"foo-bar-baz"
```

This is also less consing / coercion and you can write more transformation function to do something with characters, like transliterate them or whatever you like.

If your key argument was not a function, you could do something to this effect:

```
(ccase key-argument
  (possilbe-value-0 (do what possible value 0 does))
  (possilbe-value-1 (do what possible value 1 does))
  . . .
  (possilbe-value-N (do what possible value N does)))
```

for example, but there are really many ways to do that.

---

Similar, but w/o ppcre:

```
(defun hyphenate (string &key (case-transform #'identity))
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (loop for c across string
       do (if (upper-case-p c)
              (progn
                (when (> (file-position stream) 0)
                  (write-char #\- stream))
                (write-char (funcall case-transform c) stream))
              (write-char c stream)))))

(hyphenate "fooBarBaz")
"foo-Bar-Baz"

(hyphenate "fooBarBaz" :case-transform #'char-downcase)
"foo-bar-baz"
```